# Can't get Extra data via Intent

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-activity, android-pendingintent

**I'm trying to put extra data (string) in an intent. I use startActivity to get my extra string data on the other side.
But I can't get why it doesn't work! Here's my code :
This is the destination Activity from where I want to parse my extra data -- Recipe Activity :**

```
class RecipeActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    for (k in 0..name_arr.size-1) {
        if(temp_arr[position]==name_arr[k]){
            //to parse the id number of the selected recipe by the user to the next activity
            val i = Intent(baseContext, ResRecActivity::class.java)
            i.putExtra("ItemPosition",k)
            startActivity(i)
        }
    }
}
```

**This is the Target Activity for successful parsing of extra data -- ResRecActivity :**

```
class ResRecActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_res_rec)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        var posit : String = intent.getStringExtra("ItemPosition") //wanting to get the extra data 

        //BELOW LINE IS THE ERROR LINE
        *readJson(posit.toInt())* //Intending to parse the extra data in Integer datatype to readJson Function 
    }
}
```

**Error that I am getting is :**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.testarca/com.example.arca.ResRecActivity}: kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException
    Caused by: *kotlin.KotlinNullPointerException* 
        at com.example.arca.ResRecActivity.onCreate(ResRecActivity.kt:37)
```

**Main Aim :** 
I just want to parse the **Integer** "position" (in my case "k") from "RecipeActivity" to "ResRecActivity", for using that integer position in another function named "readJson" as a parameter to the function. 
And I am trying to achieve that using *Intent* property for Handling between the activities.

**Note:** Also give me a similar solution to parse an **ArrayList** data from one activity to another using intent.

Answer (score 1):

When you use `i.putExtra("ItemPosition",k)`, you're putting an `Int` into your extras.

Therefore you must use [`getIntExtra`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent#getIntExtra(java.lang.String,%20int)) to retrieve it:

```
val posit = intent.getIntExtra("ItemPosition", 0)
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked liked a charm. Also please tell me how to parse an ArrayList using intent, if that is possible using intent.

Answer (score 0):

**First**

replace this line

```
val i = Intent(baseContext, ResRecActivity::class.java)
```

with

```
 val i = Intent(this, ResRecActivity::class.java)
```

**Second**

You put `Int` in intent, so you should use `intent.getIntExtra("ItemPosition", -1)`

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Worked liked a charm. Also please tell me how to parse an ArrayList using intent, if that is possible using intent.